# Select all polygons that are completely within a circular buffer

Tags: qgis, polygon, vector, sql, buffer

I made several buffers around some points. Now I want to select all polygons that are completely within this buffer. My problem is that I also get the polygons that are partially outside of the buffer.

[image]

Comment: how are you doing your selection? looks like you want a contains instead of an intersects operation

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use "Vector->Research tools->Select by Location" and check the "Use selected features only" box.  You will want to include ONLY:

Include input features completely within the selection features

https://docs.qgis.org/2.6/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vector_selection_tools/selectbylocation.html

Comment: Thnx ed.hankins! That works.

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to the already given great answers, you could also use the **Select by location** tool from the *Processing Toolbox* to give you more options on how you want to select your objects:

[image: Select by location]

Answer (score 3):

There is a spatial query plugin that makes this possible. It has a 'within' operation. You can see the [QGIS docs on the plugin here.](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_spatial_query.html)

Edit: to add that you'll have to add the plugin via the Plugin Manager. If you are unfamiliar with this in QGIS, [here are the basic docs](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins.html).

Comment: I did use the spatial query plugin and selected the "within" feature. But i don't get all the polygons back that are within the buffer.